# Rails + Big Sur + pg and Spring conflict?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Once I upgraded to Big Sur, I immediately got the following error in Ruby on Rails when launching the server:

```
$ rails s
/Users/carsoncole/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin19/stringio.bundle:     warning: already initialized constant StringIO::VERSION
You've tried to invoke Spring when it's already loaded (i.e. the Spring constant is defined).

This is probably because you generated binstubs with Spring 1.0, and you now have a Spring version > 1.0 on your system. To solve this, upgrade your bundle to the latest Spring version and then run `bundle exec spring binstub --all` to regenerate your binstubs. This is a one-time step necessary to upgrade from 1.0 to 1.1.

Here's the backtrace:

/Users/carsoncole/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bootsnap 1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
/Users/carsoncole/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
/Users/carsoncole/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:318:in `block in load'
/Users/carsoncole/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/Users/carsoncole/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:318:in `load'
/Users/carsoncole/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<main>'
/Users/carsoncole/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/Users/carsoncole/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/Users/carsoncole/scout_activity/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I followed the directions given above but to no avail. Any thoughts?

If I create a new Rails app, the server starts up fine. Using Rails 6.0.3.4 and Ruby 2.7.3

One difference between the new app and my existing app is the new app did not use 'pg'. When I added 'pg' (pg-1.2.3) to the new app, the same error occurs.

[UPDATE] I think the issue may be related to Homebrew. I'm now reinstalling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, although I can’t pinpoint exactly why it worked.

I reinstalled Homebrew, and Posgresql (with HB). I also updated Xcode and the command line libraries. In the process of reinstalling homebrew and Xcode, I believe a number of libraries were updated/installed which I suspect was the issue.

Works fine now.